# federated tensorflow error when i call evaluate

Tags: tensorflow, federated

federated tensorflow error

I got "OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer" when i call evaluate(server_state)
on Federated Tensorflow

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py:238: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
  numdigits = int(np.log10(self.target)) + 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
`OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[173], line 1
----> 1 evaluate(server_state)

Cell In[171], line 8, in evaluate(server_state)
      3 keras_model.compile(
      4     loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      5     metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]  
      6 )
      7 keras_model.set_weights(server_state)
----> 8 keras_model.evaluate(central_test_data)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py:238, in Progbar.update(self, current, values, finalize)
    235     message += "\n"
    237 if self.target is not None:
--> 238     numdigits = int(np.log10(self.target)) + 1
    239     bar = ("%" + str(numdigits) + "d/%d [") % (current, self.target)
    240     prog = float(current) / self.target`

OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```